# How to change row height without using renewcommand?

Tags: tables

I have a very large table and in order to make it fit the page I need to shrink its rows. I managed to obtain the desired effect by using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}`.
However, the journal for which I am preparing the manuscript does not allow the use of `\renewcommand`. 
I tried to work around it by adding negative padding (`\\[-6pt]`) at the end of the rows, but now the vertical borders of the cell are not properly scaled, as seen below.

Do you have any idea of how this can be solved?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to typeset the table between `{\small` and `}`?

Comment: the font is already \scriptsize...

Comment: Cheat and do `\def\arraystretch{0.9}` in the `table` environment. However, I can understand disallowing `\renewcommand` for standard commands, but `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}` is a basic and approved technique.

Comment: the manuscript is for AGU journals and they do not accept shortcuts like: \newcommand, \renewcommand, \def or macros.

Comment: They probably don't want them in the document preamble, but inside a `table` environment your `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}` *must* be acceptable. This is no shortcut or dangerous technique.

Comment: I am of the same opinion...I will write an email to the editors to see if this might be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obfuscate the code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering\scriptsize
\begingroup\lccode`X=`d\lccode`Y=`e\lccode`Z=`f
\lowercase{\endgroup\csname XYZ\endcsname}\arraystretch{0.9}

\begin{tabular}{crrr}
...
\end{tabular}

\caption{Whatever}\label{foo}

\end{table}
```

The `` \begingroup\lccode`X=`d\lccode`Y=`e\lccode`Z=`f `` line sets up (locally) lowercase equivalents of `XYZ`; then inside a `\lowercase` we do `\csname XYZ\endcsname` that TeX internally converts to `\csname def\endcsname` applying those equivalents and finally builds `\def`. The initial `\endgroup` ensures that those equivalences are undone.

Instead of the two lines starting at `\begingroup` and ending at `{0.9}` you can use

```
^^5c^^64^^65^^66^^5c^^61^^72^^72^^61^^79^^73^^74^^72^^65^^74^^63^^68{0.9}
```

that's much more obfuscated.

Here we simply use the ASCII code of the characters: `^^xy` means the same as the character with ASCII code `xy`, so `^^64` is `d` and so on, while `^^5c` is the backslash.

Comment: This looks like an awesome hack :). However, I cannot make it work. I get "! Missing number, treated as zero" and I don't really understand how it \lccode works.

Comment: @Patricia Some backticks were missing. I'll add a short explanation.

Comment: Btw, the second highly obfuscated option works :)

Comment: Thank you, now they both work. Once again, brilliant workaround :)!

Comment: I am shocked, **shocked**, that you would advocate such shenanigans... +1.